# Automation of Binary Options Trading

Tags: trading, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, metatrader5

Perhaps the easiest way to automate one's Forex trading strategy is to 
create an automated trading robot (aka expert advisor) using MQL4/5 programming language, that is built into the MetaTrader Terminal platform. A more exotic option is to develop an automated trading strategy using JForex< platform from Dukascopy.

I wonder if there's anything similar for binary options trading.

What platform can I use to develop a robot, that will trade binary options according to my strategy? All the binary options trading terminals I've seen are meant for manual trading and don't have any automation capabilities.

Answer (score -1):

1. Trading instruments are pre-set by Brokers' decision

   While there are some trading platform consequences, the primary decision is Broker-side business model. If this says offer Binary Options trading, next comes the technical ( and a licensing + CAPEX + OPEX budgeting ) side of that decision.
2. Binary Options are traded on the MetaTrader Server / MetaTrader Terminal

   While there are Brokers, who operate Binary Options trading on MetaTrader Server, one may rather inspect the "depth" of such instrument-specific adaptation in advance.

   MQL4 has been long time on the market, while still there are limits and caveats for even the plain Majors trading. MetaQuotes Inc., has brought some server-side extensions, which allow some additional services to be handled on the MetaTrader Terminal side, but that does not imply your MQL4-code will have any chance to interact with these. So while you may trade Binary Options via click-able applet, **review rather carefully with the respective Broker, if / what** are MQL4-code functionalities that allow you to work with and trade their Binary Options offerings.